# How to add a waypoint route map to Leaflet Map

Tags: jquery, routes, leaflet, mapbox

We have a geographical map that needs to have a multi-waypoint route put on the map. Some extensive digging around on Leaflet, Mapbox, and third party OSRM ( https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/basic-usage/ ) have caused a couple of issues and confusions I would like to address and resolve.

### 1)

We started off using OSRM by liedman.net (https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/basic-usage/ ) which gives us a successful route mapping, but the mapping places markers, but we want to have a coloured route [As per the example here](https://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/basic-usage/)

[image]

Please see below the code that creates the above screenshot:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    /***
     * Maplink Leaflet Map
     ***/
    var osm = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={token}', {
        attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a> Ã‚Â© <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        token: 'pk.eyJ1IjoibXJtYXJ0aW5tYXAiLCJhIjoiJrbnVmY3V5Y2lsMyJ9.2k05lXmg1gEBVEPNrzWv3g'
    });

    var sat = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/satellite-v9/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={token}', {
        attribution: 'Ã‚Â© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a> Ã‚Â© <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        token: 'pk.eymY3V5Y2lsMyJ9.2k05lXmg1gEBVEPNrzWv3g'
    });

    var baseMaps = {
        "Street Map": osm,
        "Satellite": sat
    };

    var map = L.map('mapBox', {
        center: [52.342821, 1.502032],
        zoom:  13,
        zoomControl: true,
        layers: [osm]
    });

    var control = L.Routing.control({
        type: "LineString",
        waypoints: [
            L.latLng(52.373928534631, 1.5185149175591),
L.latLng(52.3743236981, 1.5218529554925),
L.latLng(52.374005250243, 1.5279998745752),
L.latLng(52.37517580779, 1.5339717879738),
L.latLng(52.375244551776, 1.5361817352395),
L.latLng(52.374178450581, 1.538741768524),
L.latLng(52.373145273275, 1.5402021415244),

L.latLng(52.371343655497, 1.5432908471328),
L.latLng(52.37089229909, 1.5463406259909),
L.latLng(52.370620846203, 1.5478912109094),
L.latLng(52.369534164635, 1.549332271737),
L.latLng(52.367736425923, 1.5516859823006),
L.latLng(52.365961272093, 1.5562747098787),
L.latLng(52.363826626776, 1.5560737222609),
L.latLng(52.363415600138, 1.5577743990103),
L.latLng(52.355134400609, 1.5636455279769),
L.latLng(52.35307405854, 1.5651541767074),
L.latLng(52.352018171547, 1.5655685369414),
L.latLng(52.350944098781, 1.5653938775016),
L.latLng(52.343370852043, 1.5641964996655),
L.latLng(52.341777872337, 1.5633339910802),
L.latLng(52.340106282238, 1.5632875706273),
L.latLng(52.33541647971, 1.5595330571513),
L.latLng(52.335002293455, 1.5583544859298),
L.latLng(52.334934485626, 1.5582168900664),
L.latLng(52.330652247898, 1.5570506936261),
L.latLng(52.330466621572, 1.5554501781789),
L.latLng(52.330643540396, 1.5489751133946),
L.latLng(52.333469429343, 1.5435341099671),
L.latLng(52.334263769345, 1.5410428672338),
L.latLng(52.334410243585, 1.5385585030839),
L.latLng(52.333564533991, 1.5337631652992),
L.latLng(52.333947661548, 1.5311802298449),
L.latLng(52.333993258268, 1.5284528979878),
L.latLng(52.333983194728, 1.5281878092106),
L.latLng(52.333847950697, 1.5260921112576),
L.latLng(52.334076866364, 1.5250531876149),
L.latLng(52.334638879879, 1.5243050496297),
L.latLng(52.335144846784, 1.5230238466705),
L.latLng(52.335670439702, 1.5204814255916),
L.latLng(52.33398972563, 1.5159136857342),
L.latLng(52.333082930757, 1.5131401642426),
L.latLng(52.333054060957, 1.5098784179832),
L.latLng(52.332670036541, 1.5088789665467),
L.latLng(52.326690203969, 1.4909360111654),
L.latLng(52.32558152194, 1.4870612949585),
L.latLng(52.324748195601, 1.4848231574432),
L.latLng(52.326028922893, 1.4834852799705),
L.latLng(52.326364282807, 1.4824840567374),
L.latLng(52.32681057286, 1.4819906579486),
L.latLng(52.325484243319, 1.4842645104118),
L.latLng(52.326732403443, 1.4818964338005),
L.latLng(52.326191596507, 1.4813254546239),
L.latLng(52.325585116918, 1.4774904528101),
L.latLng(52.325567323637, 1.4738191542329),
L.latLng(52.325366612784, 1.4733043123409),
L.latLng(52.324746214638, 1.4729914471264),
L.latLng(52.324317652178, 1.4710495594987),
L.latLng(52.323885475726, 1.4698413789914),
L.latLng(52.323702098841, 1.4681242581154),
L.latLng(52.323716353948, 1.4651895823682),
L.latLng(52.323756118351, 1.4626091953409),
L.latLng(52.32304484859, 1.4580325667347),
L.latLng(52.322873371934, 1.4552889568474),
L.latLng(52.322865774099, 1.4543195748181),
L.latLng(52.324224951186, 1.4509025657141),
L.latLng(52.324359220914, 1.4493863967275),
L.latLng(52.325392645119, 1.4454153306717),
L.latLng(52.325362752018, 1.4433578875985),
L.latLng(52.325536216782, 1.440494194372),
L.latLng(52.326593383516, 1.4387853563353),
L.latLng(52.330640025072, 1.4351062271597),
L.latLng(52.331620345052, 1.435417155417),
L.latLng(52.33341766606, 1.4348518220137),
L.latLng(52.333433473159, 1.4299786075842),
L.latLng(52.333746805263, 1.4272426304615),
L.latLng(52.335663083534, 1.4281544238335),
L.latLng(52.338724556504, 1.4286557286838),
L.latLng(52.342511464105, 1.4277154207984),
L.latLng(52.344355710515, 1.4267714620982),
L.latLng(52.345175369653, 1.4270405071525),
L.latLng(52.347606319977, 1.4294317044437),
L.latLng(52.347508064253, 1.4297178270418),
L.latLng(52.34760461698, 1.4294903194934),
L.latLng(52.348616587627, 1.4299505826722),
L.latLng(52.349255841306, 1.4296182449996),
L.latLng(52.349914810872, 1.4298455510591),
L.latLng(52.35210384858, 1.4325121790529),
L.latLng(52.353274824329, 1.4336899514406),
L.latLng(52.359027748435, 1.4375151713154),
L.latLng(52.360169618042, 1.4390729739681),
L.latLng(52.361145656854, 1.4401478429684),
L.latLng(52.364396677167, 1.4464832761285),
L.latLng(52.367670689087, 1.4495595011622),
L.latLng(52.369310462371, 1.4531551729001),
L.latLng(52.368518131827, 1.4537986218194),
L.latLng(52.367899979822, 1.4558662352753),
L.latLng(52.367868134946, 1.4575682037288),
L.latLng(52.367439607205, 1.4599150489171),
L.latLng(52.366634349945, 1.4609981366697),
L.latLng(52.365519785369, 1.4615868095752),
L.latLng(52.365391355795, 1.4628991111932),
L.latLng(52.36458066691, 1.465392154216),
L.latLng(52.362950098691, 1.4688492835633),
L.latLng(52.361315984109, 1.4724234172015),
L.latLng(52.361944608038, 1.4706216015661),
L.latLng(52.36131382831, 1.472496705368),
L.latLng(52.364113431526, 1.4733335235664),
L.latLng(52.366347860098, 1.4750370460639),
L.latLng(52.367379302163, 1.4754413295307),
L.latLng(52.364668869236, 1.4819576140315),
L.latLng(52.36411467605, 1.4830600068279),
L.latLng(52.363735616745, 1.4843230882357),
L.latLng(52.363465957373, 1.4855359986582),
L.latLng(52.36327240298, 1.4866079708467),
L.latLng(52.364106020738, 1.4900529343092),
L.latLng(52.364104898121, 1.4906993144523),
L.latLng(52.36597345132, 1.4919928178826),
L.latLng(52.367204577313, 1.4929422267725),
L.latLng(52.36836792085, 1.4925344977073),
L.latLng(52.370963900266, 1.4972066930092),
L.latLng(52.375376257668, 1.5073433378036),
L.latLng(52.374386552099, 1.5146128313911),
L.latLng(52.37383618134, 1.5185957447588),
L.latLng(52.360578009061, 1.5606020641776)        ],
        lineOptions : {
            styles: [
                {color: 'blue', opacity: 0.95, weight: 9},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.8, weight: 6},
                {color: 'red', opacity: 1, weight: 2}
            ],
            missingRouteStyles: [
                {color: 'black', opacity: 0.5, weight: 7},
                {color: 'white', opacity: 0.6, weight: 4},
                {color: 'gray', opacity: 0.8, weight: 2, dashArray: '7,12'}
            ]
        },
        show: true,
        addWaypoints: false,
        autoRoute: false,
        routeWhileDragging: false,
        geocoder: L.Control.Geocoder.nominatim(),
        draggableWaypoints: false,
        useZoomParameter: true,
        showAlternatives: false
    }).addTo(map);

    var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
    //
    //L.Routing.itinerary({
    //    pointMarkerStyle:{radius: 1,color: '#03f',fillColor: 'white',opacity: 0,fillOpacity: 0.7},
    //    //show: true
    //}).addTo(map);
    //
    //let newWaypoints = [
    //        //];

    //control.setWaypoints(newWaypoints);

});

// http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/tutorials/
// DOC : http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-control
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
    <title>Route:</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"
     integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY="
     crossorigin=""/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/includes/css/leaflet-routing-machine.css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/Control.Geocoder.css" >

    <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

   
    <style>
        #mapBox{
            width: 978px;
            height: 640px;
            float:left;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mapBox"></div>
    
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.9.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>

 <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"
     integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo="
     crossorigin=""></script>
     
    <script src='/js/leaflet-routing-machine.js'></script>
    <script src="/js/leaflet-control-geocoder_dist_Control.Geocoder.js"></script>
<!--    https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/cycling/-84.518641,39.134270;-84.512023,39.102779?geometries=geojson-->
  </div>
  </body>
```

This code outputs the waypoints as markers rather than as parts of a coloured path.

How do we make these waypoints part of the path notes rather than as waypoint flags?

I can't find the JS code that does this.

### 2)

More broadly, How can we use a system to create route maps (using predefined co-ordinates) on a leaflet map? These don't need to be user edited but do need to be readable as lines on the map rather than as pins.

I have looked through the [Leaflet Plugin List](https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html) but can't see one that fits the bill.

The one used (liedman.net) is from 2018 and has some issues as with using the OSRM server.

## How can we place a route line path on a Leaflet map in 2023?

Thank you.

## Qs that have been read :

- [Mapbox - Trying to add a route between several markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63207227/mapbox-trying-to-add-a-route-between-several-markers)
- [How to add routes (polylines) between two markers in leaflet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47963569/how-to-add-routes-polylines-between-two-markers-in-leaflet)